# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

Estoy creando una aplicación en python (3.4) con tkinter y la estoy compilando con pyinstaller.
El fragmento de código que trae el error es este:

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
known_hosts = open(self.resource_path("known_hosts")) # Linea 73
client.load_host_keys(known_hosts)
```

El error lo arroja cuando apreto en un botón que ejecuta esa parte del código, es decir, la aplicación corre lo mas bien.
El error es este:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1538, in __call__
  File "prueba.py", line 73, in aceptar
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Hernan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI124282\\known_hosts'
```

Aclaro que la estoy compilando y ejecutando en windows 10.

intenté ejecutar el exe como administrador pero sigue dando el mismo error.
Verifiqué la ruta del archivo y el mismo existe, así que descarto que el archivo no exista.
También intenté compilar el exe en un cmd con permisos de administrador, pero tampoco me dió solución.

Alguna idea ?

PD: add code...

```
    def resource_path(self, relative_path):
        """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
        base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS',     os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
        return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

Comment: El error es muy claro... verifica que el archivo, además de existir, tiene permiso de lectura. ¿qué línea es la que te da el error? ¿la del `open()` o la del `client.load_host_keys()`? ¿Te funciona si lo ejecutas como script "normal" (es decir, sin compilar con pyinstaller)

Comment: Si te funciona normalmente pero no con pyinstaller, puede ser un problema de que no has declarado ese fichero como parte del "bundle". Mira [la documentación aqui](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#using-spec-files)

Comment: El fichero está dentro del blunde. Lo compruebo cuando voy a buscar en la carpeta temporal el archivo. El archivo tiene permisos tanto de lectura como de escritura para todos. Se ejecuta sin problemas sin compilar!

Comment: Me gustaría poder probarlo en mi máquina a ver que descubro. ¿Hay alguna forma de crear un ejemplo mínimo? Si el problema es el `self.resource_path()` quizás no haga falta ni usar paramiko para reproducir el error. ¿A qué se refiere `self` en tu código?

Comment: La función está dentro de la clase Aplicación que genero para tkinter. Ahí agrego el código de la función resource_path()!

Comment: Insisto... podrías preparar un ejemplo completo mínimo que produzca el error? Entiendo que debe incluir la clase `Aplicacion` y tu implementación de `resource_path()`, así como un fichero "de prueba" que represente el recurso a cargar y la configuración necesaria para que `pyinstaller` lo incluya en el bundle. La aplicación podría simplemente al arrancar tratar de cargar un recurso (y fallar con permiso denegado, como te ocurre a tí). El resto de la funcionalidad (incluyendo paramiko) no sería en principio relevante y podría omitirse.

Comment: Es necesario paramiko, hice unos cambios en el código para demostrarte por qué.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1538, in __call__
  File "prueba.py", line 75, in aceptar
  File "site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 127, in load_host_keys
  File "site-packages\paramiko\hostkeys.py", line 91, in load
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Hernan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI17322\\known_hosts'

Comment: Paramiko intenta hacer un open al archivo known_hosts y obtengo el errno 13

Comment: Pero tu código intenta abrir antes el fichero. Tienes una línea que dice `known_hosts = open(self.resource_path("known_hosts")) # Linea 73` y en tu pregunta original era esta línea la que fallaba. Por otro lado, a `client.load_host_keys()` hay que pasarle un _nombre de fichero_, y no un fichero abierto como tu estabas haciendo. Ahora estoy confundido sobre dónde está tu verdadero error. ¿Es cuando tú haces el `open()` (en cuyo caso paramiko es suprefluo), o es cuando intenta hacerlo paramiko (en cuyo caso no me extraña, pues no le pasas un nombre de fichero sino un fichero abierto)?

Comment: Entiendo tu confusión. el open(self...) lo comenté y lo reemplacé por lo siguiente:         known_hosts = self.resource_path("known_hosts")
        client.load_host_keys(known_hosts)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85338/discussion-between-abulafia-and-hernan-bernal).